# How can i show Elevate zoom only inside the gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a Gallery where i've enable elevateZoom. This Elevate is enable outside the gallery as well. How to hide the elevate zoom outside gallery. Below is a simple code what am using. I tried using mouseleave but that doesn't seem to work.

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.rg-image-wrapper').mouseleave(function(){
            $('.zoomContainer').hide();
        });
        $('#zoombtn').on('click', function(){
            if( $('.enabled').length === 0){
                $('.zoomContainer').show();
                $("#zooom").elevateZoom({
                    zoomType: "lens",
                    lensShape : "square",
                    cursor: "crosshair"
                });     
                $(this).toggleClass('enabled');
            } 
            else{
                $(this).toggleClass('enabled');
                $('.zoomContainer').hide();
            }
       });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**ScreenShots of elevateZoom coming out of frame.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update: you want image constraint if I understand you correctly.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/vea268te/)

```
$("#zoom_01").elevateZoom({constrainType:"height", constrainSize:274, zoomType: "lens", containLensZoom: true, gallery:'gallery_01', cursor: 'pointer', galleryActiveClass: "active"});
```

[image]

Comment: nope! It is wrapped properly. Any way to hide it using jquery?

Comment: Please add css and or JSfiddle. Are you trying to do inner frame? If so simply change zoom type to inner.

Comment: @Jeeva check update demo. I think you want to constrain the lens within the pic..

Comment: norcal check this fiddle. This s what am trying to resolve. https://jsfiddle.net/tabsheerabdulla/jd181oz9/3/. I want the elevate zoom inside the scroll and hide outside

Comment: WHy do you need the photo to remain scrollable? Why not keep it in full view at 200px and contain the lens? Like this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/s9kk95wk/